# (unchecked) unchecked cast required: OnSuccessListener found: Uri

Tags: java, android, firebase-storage

I am developing an android application on Android Studio With Firebase and i am having the following  error:

[unchecked] unchecked cast
required: OnSuccessListener
found:    Uri

When I click to Show where is the problem it takes me to this code:

```
private void uploadImageToFirebaseStorage() {
        final StorageReference profileImageRef =
                FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("profilepics/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
        if(uriProfileImage!=null){
            profileImageRef.putFile(uriProfileImage)

                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            profileImageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener((OnSuccessListener<? super Uri>) uriProfileImage);
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(Profile.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
        }
    }
```

Down here is the whole class:

```
public class Profile extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final int CHOOSE_IMAGE = 101;
    TextView textView;
    EditText editText;
    ImageView imageView;
    String profileimageurl;
    private StorageReference mStorageRef;

    Uri uriProfileImage;

    FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        editText =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.nome);
        imageView=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.prefil);
        textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewVerified);

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showImageChooser();
            }
        });

                loadUserInformation();



        findViewById(R.id.login_bt).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                saveUserInformation();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if(mAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){

            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(this,Login.class));


        }

    }

    private void loadUserInformation() {

        final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        if (user != null) {


            if (user.getPhotoUrl() != null) {

                String photoUrl = user.getPhotoUrl().toString();
                Glide.with(this)
                        .load(user.getPhotoUrl().toString())
                        .into(imageView);
            }
            if (user.getDisplayName() != null) {

                String displayName = user.getDisplayName();
                editText.setText(user.getDisplayName());

            }

            if (user.isEmailVerified()) {
                textView.setText("Email verified");

            }
            else{
                textView.setText("Email not Verified(click to Verify");
                textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        user.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                Toast.makeText(Profile.this,"Verification Email Sent",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

    private void saveUserInformation() {
        String displayName = editText.getText().toString();
        if(displayName.isEmpty()){
            editText.setError("Requer Nome");
            editText.requestFocus();
            return;
        }

        FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

        if(user!=null && profileimageurl!=null){
            UserProfileChangeRequest profile = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                    .setDisplayName(displayName)
                    .setPhotoUri(Uri.parse(profileimageurl))
                    .build();
            user.updateProfile(profile)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if( task.isSuccessful()){
                                Toast.makeText(Profile.this,"Profile Updated",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });


        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==CHOOSE_IMAGE&& data !=null && data.getData()!=null){
            uriProfileImage = data.getData();
            try {
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(),uriProfileImage);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

                uploadImageToFirebaseStorage();

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    private void uploadImageToFirebaseStorage() {
        final StorageReference profileImageRef =
                FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("profilepics/"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg");
        if(uriProfileImage!=null){
            profileImageRef.putFile(uriProfileImage)

                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            profileImageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener((OnSuccessListener<? super Uri>) uriProfileImage);
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(Profile.this,e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        }
                    });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menuLogout:

                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(this,Login.class));
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void showImageChooser(){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent,"Escohe a imagem de perfil"),CHOOSE_IMAGE);
    }


}
```

Comment: @Michael done , i already changed

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but in the statement `profileImageRef.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener((OnSuccessListener<? super Uri>) uriProfileImage)`, it seems like you're casting a Uri object to an instance of an OnSuccessListener. I suspect there seems to be a logical error here.

Comment: @KaranModi i am trying send a imagem to firebase storage

Comment: As per the docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/storage/StorageReference.html#getDownloadUrl() you might be using getDownloadUrl Incorrectly.

Comment: afetr a few trys i cannt understand what is wrong with the code @KaranModi

Comment: As @KaranModi said, the `.addOnSuccessListener((OnSuccessListener<? super Uri>) uriProfileImage)` bit of your code is nonsense. You're casting a String to an OnSuccessListener, that will never work. You're going to have to change your question to explain what you're actually trying to do.